# mysql stored procedure and trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table in mysql: (`_table`) with a a few columns, one of which includes a block of text. I want to search the column with the block of text (`text`) to see if it includes specific text `[JOB]`.  If it does, I'd like to insert `Y` in another column (`data`). Or, if it includes `[JOB-M]` I'd like it to insert `M` in the previously mentioned column (`data`), If it contains neither `[JOB-M]` or `[JOB]`, then it should insert `N`.  I'd like it to follow this process every time the field (`text`) is updated or inserted.
I gather I need to create a stored procedure and a trigger, but am having a lot of trouble... any hints?
-Nat

p.s. I know how to do this in excel, but transferring this over to mysql has been troublesome. Here is my excel formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[JOB]",X6)),"Y",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[JOB-M]",X6)),"M", "N"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [INSERT trigger and an UPDATE trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) will do the trick:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER TRG_BI_JOBYMN BEFORE INSERT ON _table
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> SET NEW.data = CASE
    ->                  WHEN `text` LIKE '%[JOB]%'   THEN 'Y'
    ->                  WHEN `text` LIKE '%[JOB-M]%' THEN 'M'
    ->                  ELSE                              'N'
    ->                END;

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER TRG_BU_JOBYMN BEFORE UPDATE ON _table
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> SET NEW.data = CASE
    ->                  WHEN `text` LIKE '%[JOB]%'   THEN 'Y'
    ->                  WHEN `text` LIKE '%[JOB-M]%' THEN 'M'
    ->                  ELSE                              'N'
    ->                END;
```

Comment: thanks!! the query executes properly, but apparently triggers won't work on my godaddy shared hosting linux account because they haven't updated to mysql 5.1!!  looks like i've got to switch hosts or upgrade to a dedicated server.  I will use this infor when I get that all sorted out!  Thanks a million!